# Consuming Java Web Service In C#

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wsdl, webservice-client

I wrote a Bottom up web service in java. The service code is like the following:

```
@WebService(serviceName="CPService", name="CPService")
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use=SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class CPService {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "SendSms")
    @WebResult(name="SendResult")
    public SendResult sendSms(@WebParam(name = "smses") Sms[] smses){
        SendResult result = new SendResult();
        if(smses == null ||  smses.length == 0){
            result.OperationResult = OperationResult.MaxSizeExceed.getValue();
            return result;
        }
        result.OperationResult = OperationResult.Success.getValue();
        SmsResult[] smsResults = new SmsResult[smses.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (Sms sms : smses) {
            smsResults[i++] = new SmsResult(sms.Index);
        }
        result.SmsResults = smsResults;
        return result;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="SmsResult")
public class SmsResult {
    @XmlElement(required = true, name="Index")
    public int Index;
    @XmlElement(required = true, name="BrtelId")
    public String BrtelId;
    public SmsResult(){}
    public SmsResult(int index){
        this.Index = index;
        this.BrtelId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

Then I created a *C#* based client and I tried to call service. Service call was Ok but return values was null. After some try I understand that the problem was related to deference between array serialization in *C#* and Java.

I want to know is there any way to handle *WSDL* generation process(for exmaple using XmlElementWrapper decorator)?